# Test of Equality of mean for time series data

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures

I want to test the equality of mean returns of 4 fund managers for seven time series data of annual returns, which statistical tools would be appropriate, i am planning to use single factor ANOVA

Comment: There is a problem with anova because of the time dependence.  Here is a similar post:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70645/is-two-way-anova-appropriate     You could look into repeated measures with some time series correlation model.